# Unable to start sonarqube 7.1 on mac

Tags: sonarqube

I had downloaded latest sonarqube 7.1. And trying to start using command:

```
./bin/macosx-universal-64/sonar.sh console
```

But, It's not get started. Logs are:

```
Running SonarQube...
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    | 
jvm 1    | 2018.04.26 14:57:34 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /Users/deepakagrawal/softwares/sonarqube-7.1/temp
jvm 1    | 2018.04.26 14:57:34 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
jvm 1    | 2018.04.26 14:57:34 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/Users/deepakagrawal/softwares/sonarqube-7.1/elasticsearch]: /Users/deepakagrawal/softwares/sonarqube-7.1/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Epath.conf=/Users/deepakagrawal/softwares/sonarqube-7.1/temp/conf/es
jvm 1    | 2018.04.26 14:57:34 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
jvm 1    | 2018.04.26 14:57:34 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
jvm 1    | 2018.04.26 14:57:34 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
jvm 1    | Error: Could not find or load main class -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
jvm 1    | 2018.04.26 14:57:34 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
jvm 1    | 2018.04.26 14:57:34 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2018.04.26 14:57:34 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I tried other versions like 7.0. But it's still not working.

I had installed Oracle Java 8.

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Did you check [all logs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Troubleshooting) ? Anything relevant there ?

Comment: Which properties did you edit in conf/wrapper.conf and conf/sonar.properties ?

Comment: **jvm 1    | 2018.04.26 14:57:34 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
** --- This line tells me that something to do with the elastic search. Please share the es.log from sonar_home/logs?

Comment: adding a gist would be very helpful. https://gist.github.com/

Comment: I have this issue too.

Comment: bingo: `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root`

Comment: I've been running into so many issues that using the official Docker image was so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

## root user will not work

Looks like elastic search is failing to start. Do not attempt to run sonar as a root. Elastic is designed to prevent you from doing running as root.

`$ tail logs/es.log`

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:103) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.4.jar:6.8.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.4.jar:6.8.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:333) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.4.jar:6.8.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.4.jar:6.8.4]
    ... 6 more
```

If you are running as root:

1. Prepare system user.
2. Open sonar.sh find RUN_AS_USER and assign your system user.

## Notes

If you were using root to avoid file permission issues and just quickly want to get something running, you can do this instead:

```
sudo chown $(whoami) temp logs -Rv
```

Comment: While this isn't for the OP, anyone else who came here as a newbie will also want to know that your java version may not be new enough (though the logs will tell you that). In case you're wondering, the logs are at `logs/sonar.log`

Answer (score -1):

After a macOS update to 10.14.5 I got a similar log. I found out that write permissions were removed from `/opt/sonarqube/temp/`, which are needed by elastic search (`ls -l /opt/sonarqube/temp/`). After re-adding write permissions using `chmod`, sonarqube started successfully again.